# How to create static html file with angular 4 library

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to create static html site with angular 4 ?

The scenario is i have got angular 4 ts files then from that I want to provide index.html (with other folders, assets etc) and I do not need any server to run this.

Comment: It's possible to create a site with a single HTML file, of course. And it's possible to create a site that runs from a local filesystem. But "click on this file and everything works" is awfully broad.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking deployment perspective then Yes it is possible. Use AOT compilation and build it for production environment. If you are using angular CLI then it is as simple as

```
ng build --prod
```

The command will generate dist directory which will have html, javascript and other assets provided angular cli is properly configured.

But please note if you are using any http calls then it may not work because of the cors issue.